# How do I access the tr of this table using HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html, .net, xml, html-agility-pack

So I am currently playing around with HtmlAgiltiyPack trying to understand how traversing through an XML document like a HTML document to see how works and how it flows.

The website I selected was this one https://www.kijiji.ca

What I am trying to do is to grab the Title of the the `Featured` listings
but I have stumbled onto an issue.

I managed to find all the `Featured` tables but now I would like to dive into the current one I am at and find it's `tr` which contains the class `description`.

This is what I have so far.

```
private static string URL = "https://www.kijiji.ca/b-renovation-contracting-handyman/ontario/home-renovations/k0c753l9004";
        private static HtmlWeb client = new HtmlWeb();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var DOM = client.Load(URL);
            var Featured = DOM.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[contains(@class,'top-feature')]");
            foreach (var Listing in Featured)
            {

            }
        }
```

There are a few things I wonder, for one, the thing I asked above, how to *dive in deeper* and also..

What I have right there.
what does `Listing` actually contain, does it contain all the childnodes? Which I guess in this case would be `tbody` looking at this for reference.
[image: Visual reference]

Or would it contain all the childnodes, not only `tbody` but also `tr` & `td`?

Answer (score 0):

**How about this Example :**

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(@"<html><body><p><table id=""foo""><tr><th>hello</th></tr><tr><td>world</td></tr></table></body></html>");
foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table")) {
Console.WriteLine("Found: " + table.Id);
foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr")) {
    Console.WriteLine("row");
    foreach (HtmlNode cell in row.SelectNodes("th|td")) {
        Console.WriteLine("cell: " + cell.InnerText);
    }
}
}
```

Note that you can make it prettier with LINQ-to-Objects if you want:

```
var query = from table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table").Cast<HtmlNode>()
        from row in table.SelectNodes("tr").Cast<HtmlNode>()
        from cell in row.SelectNodes("th|td").Cast<HtmlNode>()
        select new {Table = table.Id, CellText = cell.InnerText};

foreach(var cell in query) {
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", cell.Table, cell.CellText);
}
```